# nodejs getting running processs/promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to check if any promises are running in a Node application? Let's say we have the following code snippet:

```
router.post('/someEndpoint', async (req, res) => {
    await someFunctions();
});
```

We want to create an endpoint `/getRunningProcess` to check if there are any running processes in the application. Is there a generic way to do this instead of writing application-specific code to check the status of each process individually? The code for `/getRunningProcess` should look something like this:

```
router.get('/getRunningProcess', (req, res) => {
   // code to check for running processes or active promises
   ...
   res.status(200).json({ "process": process})
});
```

we initially planned on doing it the proper way by writing application specific code to status check the application for any running processes but it would take us a considerable amount of time to do it for everything.

Comment: First off, promises don't "run".  They are merely a notification system for some other asynchronous operation.  Second, there is no built-in scheme in nodejs to find all promises still in the pending state and, even if you could, you would not know what operation they were monitoring.   Third, you speak of "processes" and it's hard to know what you're talking about here.   Most asynchronous operation in nodejs (file, network, timers, etc...) are NOT separate processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to count the number of unresolved requests.

There is no built-in way to find the count of promises in the pending state. You could make use of the [on-finished](https://github.com/jshttp/on-finished) middleware to keep track of unresolved requests.

Also, it looks like you are using expressjs. So, I will write a sample using expressjs syntax.

You could create a middleware to keep track of unresolved requests.

```js
const onFinished = require('on-finished')

const unresolvedRequestIds = new Set()
const requestTracker = (_, res, next) => {
  const id = Math.random();
  unresolvedRequestIds.add(id)
  onFinished(res, () => {
    unresolvedRequestIds.delete(id)
  });
  next();
};
```

Now, you can use this `requestTracker` middleware before any custom middleware:

```js
router.post('/someEndpoint', requestTracker, async (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

To get your unresolved request count, you could simply count the number of entries in `unresolvedRequestIds`:

```js
router.get('/getUnresolvedRequestCount', (req, res) => {
   res.status(200).json({ unresolvedRequestCount: unresolvedRequestIds.size })
});
```

Instead of adding the `requestTracker` middleware in all your async routes individually, you can add it at the top level of the app. But do note that this may also count non-async unresolved requests.

```js
app.use(requestTracker);
```